# Cannot get Bluetooth to work on Mac Pro 3,1 running Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, uefi, bluetooth, macintosh

I've been running Arch Linux for about a year and I have never been able to get the Bluetooth working. 
It used to not show up anywhere but recently I set up my wireless adapter with wl and when I did `lsusb` it showed a USB Bluetooth adapter.

Bus 004 Device 003: ID 05ac:1000 Apple, Inc. Bluetooth HCI MacBookPro (HID mode)

I also recently added a PCI USB hub and I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

```
05:00.0 USB controller: Fresco Logic FL1100 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 10)
```

I also should have all the right other packages

bluedevil 1:5.21.3-1
blueman 2.1.4-1
bluez 5.56-2
bluez-libs 5.56-2
bluez-qt 5.80.0-1
bluez-utils 5.56-2
gnome-bluetooth 3.34.5-1
pulseaudio-bluetooth 14.2-3

I also have all the correct kernel modules loaded.

btusb                  69632  0
btrtl                  28672  1 btusb
btbcm                  20480  1 btusb
btintel                32768  1 btusb
bluetooth             749568  11 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb

But when I do `ls /sys/class/bluetooth` is empty.

I was thinking it could have something to do with how the order in witch the kernel starts the Bluetooth stuff. 
I think I read somewhere that the Wi-Fi card starting before the Bluetooth stuff can cause issues in some Macs but I don't remember where I heard that. 
I also thought could be related to the EFI vars because `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/` contains file called EFIBluetoothDelay-7c436110-ab2a-4bbb-a880-fe41995c9f82, bluetoothActiveControllerInfo-7c436110-ab2a-4bbb-a880-fe41995c9f82 and boot-feature-usage-62bf9b1c-8568-48ee-85dc-dd3057660863, maybe the firmware is never starting some Bluetooth related thing but already in way over my head, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, first of all I missing some firmware which looked like this in dmesg

```
[    5.601521] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode11.fw failed with error -2
[    5.601549] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode11.fw failed with error -2
[    5.601576] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode11.fw failed with error -2
[    5.601595] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode11.fw failed with error -2
[    5.601597] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode11.fw" not found
[    5.601599] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode11.fw" not found
[    5.601600] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.
```

I then followed instruction [here](http://linuxwireless.sipsolutions.net/en/users/Drivers/b43/) to fix that and had to install bluez-hid2hci so that my card would work even though it was in HID mode. Hope this helps someone in a similar issue.